# Using Ajax to create PHP session and echo results

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm using ajax to pass data to a php session in order to save the contents of a js powered shopping cart. Here is the test js code:

```
//js.html

<html>
<body>
<script>   
function addCart(){
    var brandName = $('iframe').contents().find('.section01a h2').text();

    $.post("sessions.php", {"productName": brandName}, function(results) {
             //success alert
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the php code:

```
//session.php
<?php
   session_start();
   // store session data
   $_SESSION['productName'] = $_POST['productName'];
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
   //retrieve session data
   echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['productName'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```

However what I need is after having saved the data to the session, I want to output it to the user in a mini cart in the sidebar.

When I run `js.html` it successfully passes the data to `sessions.php`. However the `echo` isn't displayed in `js.html`. If I run `sessions.php` then the `echo` displays but isn't in the page I need.

My question is, either via PHP or js, how do I then echo or display this data to the user on the page I need?

Thanks

Comment: surely this should be tagged ajax?

Comment: yea, it should, sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `session.php` to this:

```
<?php
   session_start();

   // store session data
   $_SESSION['productName'] = $_POST['productName'];

   //retrieve session data
   echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['productName'];
?>
```

And in your HTML code:

```
function addCart(){
    var brandName = $('iframe').contents().find('.section01a h2').text();

    $.post("sessions.php", {"name": brandName}, function(results) {
        $('#SOME-ELEMENT').html(results);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("sessions.php", {"productName": brandName}, function(results) {
         alert(results.productName);
},"json");




//session.php
<?php
   session_start();
   // store session data
   $_SESSION['productName'] = $_POST['productName'];
   echo json_encode(array('productName' => $_SESSION['productName']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Pure Javascript**

The echo isn't appearing because you're making an `AJAX` call. I don't see what's stopping you from outputting the details in the `JS` code, underneath where you make the `Ajax` request.

```
$.post("sessions.php", {"name": brandName}, function(results) {
         //As in put the code here.
});
```

**With the mootools Library**

Alternatively, you can look into the `mootools` library. That library has a `Request` object, with an `onSuccess` method. You can port your shopping basket code into that `onSuccess` method.

Comment: jquery also has those callback functions, no need for mootools

Comment: thanks for the reply. Thing is, I'm still quite new in terms of how php and js interact. I'm currently reading this tutorial http://www.darian-brown.com/pass-a-php-array-to-javascript-as-json-using-ajax-and-json_encode/ and aprpently, I should encode the php array into json and then output it via js? Is there any alternative methods e.g. via php?